# Approximating an element in the domain of an unbounded operator by a sequence in a dense subset of the domain.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $T$ be a closed unbounded (in my case also symmetric) operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with dense domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$, and let $f\in \mathcal{D}(T)$.  Suppose there is a dense subspace $Y$ of $\mathcal{H}$ contained in $\mathcal{D}(T)$.  If I choose a sequence $f_n$ in $Y$ converging to $f$, under what conditions, if any, can I ensure that $Tf_n\to Tf$? The convergence of $Tf_n$ may be taken to be strong or weak. I know that $Tf$ is defined, but is it the limit of $Tf_n$?

Indeed, supposing my Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, I'm even interested in the $w^*$ convergence of the functionals $(Tf_n,\dot\:)$, where $(\dot\:,\dot\:)$ is the $L^2$-inner product. (These functionals are of course bounded on $\mathcal{D}(T)$ and so extend by continuity to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which, by Riesz's lemma means they still take the form $(Tf_n,\dot\:)$.)

A related (and equivalent, by Banach-Steinhaus) question is, whether the sequence $Tf_n$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Taking strong convergence, I think the condition is that $T$ is the closure of the restriction of $T$ to $Y$. See [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m511/unboundedReview.pdf) p.1 . EDIT : That's if you know $\lim Tf_n$ exists.

Comment: I mean, are you asking "If I choose a sequence $f_n$ in $Y$ converging to $f$, under what conditions, if any, can I ensure that $Tf_n$ converges ..." or "If I choose a sequence $f_n$ in $Y$ converging to $f$, such that $Tf_n$ converges, under what conditions, if any, can I ensure  ..." ?

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'm asking about the former. I know that $Tf$ and $Tf_n$ exist, and $f_n\to f$, but I don't know whether or when $Tf_n\to Tf$, or even if $Tf_n\to g$ for some $g$. It's very opaque to me. If I knew that $Tf_n\to g$, then things would be quite easy, I could use the closeness of $T$.

Comment: There are examples in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ where $\parallel f_n\parallel _2 \to 0$ but $\parallel \frac{d}{dx}f_n \parallel _2$ does not converge (eg., increasingly oscillatory functions). Are you asking for conditions on $T$ so that this won't happen?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in when this won't happen, given that $Tf$ is defined. The idea is I can choose the sequence $f_n$. I'm free to choose it from a dense set $Y$ contained in $\mathcal{D}(T)$, so it seems plausible that there might be ways to choose this sequence so that $Tf_n$ converges to $Tf$. For example, if $T=\Delta$, the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $Y=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is there a way to choose $f_n\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ converging to $f\in \mathcal{D}(\Delta)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in such a way that $\Delta f_n\to \Delta f$?

Comment: Let $U$ be the restriction of $T$ to $Y$. Look at [Kato p. 166](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf#page=166). As I understand it, if $U$ is closable with closure $T$ then there exists the sequence you want (it doesn't tell you how to construct it). I could give you an example of a restriction that is not closable.

Comment: I take back that last sentence. There are [examples of non-closable operators](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47418/nice-classes-of-non-closable-operators) , but not what I had in mind. For symmetric operators the usual approach is to show that $T$ is essentially self-adjoint on $Y$. Then its self-adjoint extension is its closure.

Comment: Thanks, Keith, I appreciate your help.  The problem with taking the closure of the restriction is that it's happening in the graph norm, in which case we're already assuming that Tf_n converges, because (f_n,Tf_n) does (in the graph norm).  I believe $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is already a Banach space with respect to this norm, if $T$ is closed, so my question really has to do with the Hilbert space norm. Given only that $f_n\to f$ on a dense subspace of $\mathcal{D}(T)$ and that $Tf$ exists, how can we ensure $Tf_n$ at least converges, or is uniformly bounded, in the Hilbert space norm?

Comment: It's possible that $Y$ is not a core of $T$, so $f$ might not be in $\mathcal{D}(\overline {U})$. Then there is no sequence $U$-convergent to $f$ . I am reviewing this stuff myself. I find the abstract concepts 
slippery without examples. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183426/is-the-closure-of-a-symmetric-operator-unique) is an example where a restriction has many closed extensions which are not it's closure.