# Closure of a differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

Consider $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\subset L^{2}[0,1]\to L^{2}[0,1]$ given by $$A:=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}},\qquad\mathcal{D}(A):=C^{2}_{0}(0,1)$$

Now, I assume that the closure of $A$ is its extension defined on $C^{2}_{0}[0,1]$. Then am I right in thinking that this is this densely defined if $\overline{C_{0}^{2}[0,1]}=L^{2}[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator is densely-defined, and it is closable. So the closure of the operator in question is densely-defined as well.

I'm not sure about your notation $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$; does it mean the functions vanish at the endpoints, or does it mean compactly supported in $(0,1)$? Unfortunately, I've seen that notation used in both ways.

If $C_0^{\infty}(0,1)$ is the initial domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$, and we're assuming compact support, then the closure of $A$ has a domain consisting of $f \in L^2[0,1]$ which may be modified on a set of measure $0$ to obtain a twice absolutely continuous function $\tilde{f}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{f}'(0)=\tilde{f}(1)=\tilde{f}'(1)=0$, and $\tilde{f}''\in L^2$.

Comment: Isn't it like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183426/is-the-closure-of-a-symmetric-operator-unique) ?

Comment: @KeithMcClary : What I have written is correct. The closure will no longer consist of twice continuously differentiable functions. They will be $C^1$, but the first derivative will be absolutely continuous, with an $L^2$ second derivative. The homogeneous endpoint conditions for the function and the first derivative in the initial domain are preserved in the closure. So, if the functions vanish at $0,1$ and the derivatives are not restricted, the same will be true of the closure. If the functions and first derivatives vanish at $0,1$, then that will be true for the closure as well.

Comment: @TrialAndError Are you intentionally writing $C^{\infty}$ or do you really mean $C^{2}$?

Comment: @user3482534 : Use either. It's not going to change the discussion of closure. The only issue is whether you mean $C_0^2$ to mean $f$ vanishes at the endpoints or vanishes identically near the endpoints; in the latter case $f'$ also vanishes at the endpoints.

Comment: @TrialAndError $C_{0}^{2}$ means compactly supported in $(0,1)$.